# Multiple predefined datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, daterangepicker

Hi I'm using this [datepicker](https://datepicker.com). I followed this [code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dangrossman/bd8cf6efbba1c2123adc/raw/7dddbded90278b1f65b02df60c50a34a94dbf14a/DRP%20Example%204.js) for the predefined ranges now I want to have multiple daterangepicker in the page. How should I do it without repeating the code for each daterangepicker.

Comment: Add same class for each div and target datepicker with class name.

Comment: @Afsar the problem is the `cb` function. as you can see there is a selector inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code to create multiple daterangepicker with single code

```
<div id="reportrange1" class="pull-right daterangepicker" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>
<div id="reportrange2" class="pull-right daterangepicker" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>
<div id="reportrange3" class="pull-right daterangepicker" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        console.log(this.element)
        this.element.html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        //$('.daterangepicker span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('.datepicker').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
</script>
```

In call back function this.element is used to access current target element

Comment: thanks this works. just need to tweak some codes though.